# Problems with collapsible/expandable nested table rows

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a table that has a structure like this:

```
Project
--Category
----File
----File
----File
--Category
----File
Project
--Category
----File
----File
```

The code that creates the table uses PHP to get the data from a database and looks like this:

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-row" tabindex="1">
            <th class="fixed-header"></th>
            <th>Dateiname</th>
            <th>Benutzer</th>
            <th>Erstelldatum</th>
            <th>Änderungsdatum</th>
            <th>Erste Zeile</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        include_once('connect.php');

        //loop projects
        $resultProjects = $connect->query("SELECT project.name, project.idProject FROM project,user,user_has_project WHERE user.idUser = user_has_project.user_idUser AND user_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
        if($resultProjects->num_rows > 0) {
          echo "<tbody>";
          while($row = $resultProjects->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultProjectID = $row['idProject'];
            echo "<tr class='".$row['idProject']." table-row project-marker' tabindex='1'>";
            echo "<th><img src='images/arrow_right.gif' class='expand expandProjectBtn'><img src='images/arrow_down.gif' class='collapse collapseProjectBtn'></th>";
            echo "<td class='table-project'>".$row['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            //loop categories
            $resultCategories = $connect->query("SELECT category.name, category.idCategory FROM category,user,user_has_category WHERE user.idUser = user_has_category.user_idUser AND user_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
            if($resultCategories->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $resultCategories->fetch_assoc()) {
                $resultCategoryID = $row['idCategory'];
                echo "<tr class='".$row['idCategory']." table-row category-marker' tabindex='1'>";
                echo "<th><img src='images/arrow_right.gif' class='expand toggleCategoryBtn'><img src='images/arrow_down.gif' class='collapse toggleCategoryBtn'></th>";
                echo "<td class='table-category'>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                //loop files
                $resultFiles = $connect->query("SELECT file.name AS 'filename', file.description AS 'filedescription', category.name AS 'categoryname', project.name AS 'projectname', user.name AS 'username', idFile, createDate, editDate
                  FROM file JOIN file_has_project ON idFile = file_has_project.file_idFile
                            JOIN file_has_category ON idFile = file_has_category.file_idFile
                            JOIN project ON idProject = file_has_project.project_idProject
                            JOIN category ON idCategory = file_has_category.category_idCategory
                            JOIN user_has_project ON idProject = user_has_project.project_idProject
                            JOIN user_has_category ON idCategory = user_has_category.category_idCategory
                            JOIN user ON idUser = user_has_category.user_idUser
                            WHERE user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' AND idCategory = '".$resultCategoryID."' AND idProject = '".$resultProjectID."'
                            ORDER BY file.name ASC");
                if ($resultFiles->num_rows > 0) {
                  while($row = $resultFiles->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr class='".$row['idFile']." table-row file-marker' tabindex='1' draggable=true>";
                    echo "<th class='table-edit-button fixed-header'><img src='images/open.gif' /></th>";
                    echo "<td class='table-file'>".$row['filename']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['createDate']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['editDate']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['filedescription']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          echo "</tbody>";
        }
        ?>
      </table>
```

The database ID's that get written in the rows as the first class are used so that I can determine which row got clicked. But that's not really important for the problem I'm having.

The problem is as follows: I can collapse the categories so that the files get hidden. And I can collapse the projects so that the categories together with the files get hidden. But when I collapse a category first and then collapse the project which the category belongs to and expand it afterwards the files get toggled again. But I want that the files stay hidden when I expand a project which has a collapsed category in it.

This is the code I use to collapse and expand categories and projects (it's wrapped by a `$(document).ready(function() {});`:

```
function toggleTableCategory() {
    var className = $(this).closest('tr').next().attr('class').split(' ')[2];
    var element = $(this).closest('tr').next();

    while(className == 'file-marker') {
      element.toggle();
      element = element.next();
      className = element.attr('class').split(' ')[2];
    }

    $(this).closest('tr').find('img').toggle();
  }

  function collapseTableProject() {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('.project-marker', ':visible').toggle();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('img').toggle();
  }

  function expandTableProject() {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('.project-marker').toggle();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('img').toggle();
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".toggleCategoryBtn", toggleTableCategory);
  $(document).on("click", ".expandProjectBtn", expandTableProject);
  $(document).on("click", ".collapseProjectBtn", collapseTableProject);
```

The code to collapse the categories seems to be overly complicated. I tried using `.nextUntil('.category-marker')` but with this I had a problem where it also toggled the next project row when I toggled the last category of a project, so I had to do it this way.

My final question now is: How can I save the state of the collapsed categories so that they collapsed when I expand a project.

Additional question: It is possible to move the files from category to category and from project to project via drag&drop. To give the user immediate feedback I do an AJAX call when this happens and draw the table new. It would be great to save the state of the toggled categories and projects for that too. But I have no idea how to approach this because the table is always created with PHP and fed with data from a MySQL database.

If you need anymore information to help me let me know and I will edit it in.

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?